# How to set one table header for all table datas in tbody?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I work with dynamically created tables, and i have issues, i have dynamically created td with some numbers, and just one fixed table header, which i need to have only one, but in this case table looks agile :

[image]

How i can fit one table header for all table datas?

[image]

I try to use `colspan` but i just can add only fixed value.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/zsm47dt1/17/

Comment: If your html is generated dynamically, you can just set the attribute `colspan="3"` on element `th` while generating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
$('tbody').each(function(){
    var colspan = $(this).find('tr:first td').length;
  $(this).prev().find('th').attr('colspan', colspan);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnb0pxzq/